# How can I put custom, color ascii art into Metasploit?

Tags: ascii-art, metasploit

I'd like to add to or change the ASCII art that gets displayed on startup in Metasploit.

Where is/are the file(s) I need to edit to do this, and what is the syntax?  How can I include color in the art?  Does it support Unicode characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The banners are defined in the ruby source code, in `msf/lib/msf/ui/banner.rb`.
They're simple [Ruby strings](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Strings_-_Creation_and_Basics#General_Delimited_Strings), delimited usually by single quotes or `%Q{`/`}` if formatting placeholders are used. Between these strings, there's just a comma. Just add one to the array, they are chosen by random (at the end of the file).

You should adhere to Ruby string rules (don't put `'` in there if you use them as delimiters, for example). Ruby apparently has some unicode issues, but the Ruby docs will probably tell you more about this.

Metasploit banners support the colors and formatting (bold, underline) defined in `msf/lib/rex/ui/text/color.rb` — basically the regular 16 or so terminal colors.

Comment: Clearly more of an RTFSC - Read The Fine Source Code :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having a hard time figuring out what the delimiter is between art works.  Also, are there any characters I should exclude from the "images"?

Comment: @Iszi I added a bit to my answer. Remember, you're programming Ruby if you're editing these files, so jut consult the Ruby docs if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Metasploit will parse it and output the color... it removes spaces and can mess up your spacing.

variable = "%cyn" + "Make me cyan color!!!" + "%clr"

print_line(variable)

Referenced here
https://github.com/pwnieexpress/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/rex/ui/text/color.rb

```
str.gsub!(/%cya/, pre_color+colorize('cyan')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%red/, pre_color+colorize('red')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%grn/, pre_color+colorize('green')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%blu/, pre_color+colorize('blue')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%yel/, pre_color+colorize('yellow')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%whi/, pre_color+colorize('white')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%mag/, pre_color+colorize('magenta')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%blk/, pre_color+colorize('black')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%dred/, pre_color+colorize('dark', 'red')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%dgrn/, pre_color+colorize('dark', 'green')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%dblu/, pre_color+colorize('dark', 'blue')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%dyel/, pre_color+colorize('dark', 'yellow')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%dcya/, pre_color+colorize('dark', 'cyan')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%dwhi/, pre_color+colorize('dark', 'white')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%dmag/, pre_color+colorize('dark', 'magenta')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%und/, pre_color+colorize('underline')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%bld/, pre_color+colorize('bold')+post_color)
str.gsub!(/%clr/, pre_color+colorize('clear')+post_color)
```